# Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ) getting in spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

```
public Integer insertEncashLeaveRecordForEmp(
            final EncashedLeaveRecord encashRecord) {
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

        Integer update = null;
        final String sql = "INSERT INTO lms_dat_encashcarryoverleaves(EncashCarry_NumOfLeaves,"
                + "fk_EncashCarry_empId,EncashCarry_AppliedDate, "
                + "fk_EncashCarry_StatusId, fk_EncashCarry_LeaveTypeID, "
                + "fk_EncashCarry_UpdatedById,EncashCarry_UpdatedOn) "
                + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,now())";
/*
        try {
            update = misJdbcTemplate
                    .update(sql, encashRecord.getNumberOfLeaves(), encashRecord
                            .getEmployeeId(),
                            new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()),
                            encashRecord.getLeaveStatusId(), encashRecord
                                    .getLeaveTypeId(), encashRecord
                                    .getEmployeeId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }*/

        try {

            jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(
                        Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql,
                            new String[] { "pk_EncashCarry_ECId" });


                    ps.setFloat(0, encashRecord.getNumberOfLeaves());
                    ps.setInt(2, encashRecord.getEmployeeId());
                    ps.setDate(3,  new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    ps.setInt(4,encashRecord.getLeaveStatusId());
                    ps.setInt(5,encashRecord.getLeaveTypeId());
                    ps.setInt(6,encashRecord
                            .getEmployeeId());


                    return ps;
                }
            }, keyHolder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
    }
```

I am trying to save above values using spring jdbc template but getting this exception.

Exception

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:842)
    at com.thbs.intranet.rest.dao.misdatabase.impl.EncashedLeaveRecordsDaoImpl.insertEncashLeaveRecordForEmp(EncashedLeaveRecordsDaoImpl.java:244)
    at com.thbs.intranet.rest.service.impl.EmployeeLeaveServiceImpl.applyEncashLeaveByEmp(EmployeeLeaveServiceImpl.java:1218)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.applyEncashLeaveByEmp(Unknown Source)
    at com.thbs.intranet.rest.resource.EmployeeResource.applyEncashLeaveByEmp(EmployeeResource.java:934)
    at com.thbs.intranet.rest.resource.EmployeeResource$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f9a9f6b5.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.thbs.intranet.rest.resource.EmployeeResource$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1d5273d3.applyEncashLeaveByEmp(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1357)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1289)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1239)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:497)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:684)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).
```

Answer (score 3):

The index parameters in PreparedStatements start on 1, not 0. If you check oracle documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

In any method description:

`setFloat(int parameterIndex, double x)`

Parameters:
    parameterIndex - the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, ...
    x - the parameter value

So try to change:

From

```
 ps.setFloat(0, encashRecord.getNumberOfLeaves());
```

To

```
 ps.setFloat(1, encashRecord.getNumberOfLeaves());
```